# Is there a secure (https) official site for CentOS iso hashes?

Tags: centos

When I download a CentOS ISO the mirror has sha1sum.txt and other hash files, but I can't verify that these files haven't been tampered with as well.  (One exmaple http://mirrors.sonic.net/centos/6.5/isos/x86_64/)

I'd like an https (secure) download from centos.org of just the sha1sum.txt, but I can't find this anywhere.

Comment: There's also a PGP signature for those sha1sums (.asc file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solution, first you can try [every link from mirror list](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/6/isos/x86_64/) in `https://` and you could also download the official bittorent file because bitorrent include a checksum checking.

Comment: The official bittorrent link is offered via https (secure).

Comment: is it a question ?

Comment: I have to assume that the mirrors may be compromised so I want just an official Centos.org original source.

That doesn't appear to be possible so my next best option appears to be hitting a large number of mirrors via an insecure link and taking a vote of how many have the same hash file.